# Java FileReader not finding file even with absolute path

Tags: java, file, file-io, compiler-errors, filenotfoundexception

For some reason no matter how specific I get, how many common errors I dig through, FileReader cannot find the file I want.

I have tried using absolute locations, I have checked to make sure my file isn't test.txt.txt, but no matter what I look for or how I look for it I get:

> java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

The below is the test code I'm using to try and find the problem

[My problem with file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh6Y3.png)

```
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test {
    public Test(){
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/home/snake-egg/IdeaProjects/Test/src/testing123.txt.txt");
        fr.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the code not finding the file. That has to do with your code not even **compiling**, because you failed to properly catch or declare a checked exception. A code that doesn't compile doesn't run. If it doesn't run, there's no way it can or can't find a file. Google for "Java exceptions tutorial", and read.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the absolute path.The relative path is of course not found